# How can I rename a .app file?

Tags: xcode, xcode7, rename

I have created a project by duplicating an existing project and renaming the project and schema. Can I rename the .app file from within Xcode?

[image]

I already have try this [RENAMING TUTORIAL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/RenamingaProject/RenamingaProject.html) from Apple but it didn't rename my folders and my .app file.

Comment: Look the values in Info.plist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

**Build Settings -> Packaging -> Release Name**

Answer (score 0):

Double click your Project name and rename your project.  Note that it will rename your application name and product name not folder name on physical drive.

[image]